# Subtracting two float variables and comparing shell script

Tags: shell, unix, floating-point, sh

I have two floating-point variables, time and prev_time, and I need to subtract them, and check if less than 0. I've looked up in dozens of forums, but can't seem to find an answer that works. I need to do something similar to:

```
if [[ `expr $time-$prev_time | bc` -lt 0 ]]
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your use of `[[ ... ]]`, I'll assume you are using `bash`. If you only care that the difference is less than 0, you only care that `$time` is less than `$prev_time`. You can split the floating point values into its integer parts, then compare them separately:

```
IFS=. read time_int time_frac <<< $time
IFS=. read prev_in prev_frac <<< $prev_time
if (( time_int < prev_int || (time_int == prev_int && time_frac < prev_frac) )); then
```

Or, you can use `bc` this way (plus, it's POSIX compliant):

```
if [ "$( echo "$time - $prev_time < 0" | bc )" = 1 ];
```

`bc` outputs 1 if the comparison is true, 0 if false.